# Jquery Animate not working properly when viewed in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a link to a slide code.
http://jsfiddle.net/K2JBg/24/
This code for slider works fine in chrome and firefox but the last image is missing and the left portion is not appropriate when viewed in ie7/8 quirks mode

Comment: working fine for me on IE7/8.

Comment: please avoid developing for quirksmode. that's just so 1776.

Comment: well i know that very well....but i cant force the customer to use a particular browser in a particular mode to see my web page.hence i need to take care of each and every browser

Comment: you can force a mode. simply include a valid doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a check after it reaches -1200px of left position, because after the last image, if you keep press the button its left value will keep decreasing from -1200 to -1500 and so on. so you can disable the button after reaching -1200px of left or get the first image. as its working fine in ie 7/8 for me.

Comment: well the problem is before i reach the point that u just suggested.I'm having this problem rite from image one